# Error on loop disk in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mount

I had a disk, but unfortunately it had errors from a hard reset on the laptop power.

**How do I know?**

```
$ file cache.disk 
cache.disk: Linux rev 1.0 ext3 filesystem data, UUID=1c8cad78-5572-43f7-8165-bc17c86edfce (needs journal recovery) (errors) (large files)
```

Thus, it cant be mount on `fstab`.

**Question**

How to fix these errors?

**Way to solve:**

At least I found the way to solve this by entering the following command:

```
fsck.ext3 -y -v cache.disk
```

- y mean if prompt anything assuming yes
- v mean showing the progress

Comment: So did you fix the errors or not? If you were able to solve them, post your solution as an answer below and accept it in two days.

Comment: superuser told me i need 7 hours later in order to be able post the answer, so i took a chance to re-edit my post with the answer, before i forget to re-answer the known thing..

Comment: Oh okay fine then :)

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that `fsck -y -v /your/device/here` is the way to go, as far as resolving a crashed file system. It should be noted that you should never run fsck on a live and mounted file system to prevent other services from modifying the filesystem while it is being worked on.

Comment: fortunately, there is only data and no file system on it..

Comment: That does make it easier. ;)